# Is there any way to determine is csv with header or not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Writing an application that accept only csv file with header. 
So trying to detect is csv file have header or not. 
Is there any things to do that.

Comment: How it should look in your opinion? header is exactly same as any other line.

Comment: There's no standard way of defining headers in a CSV file, but convention dictates that the first line, and only the first line, is headers. People are free to do whatever they want and, in the process, make your life as a developer absolutely miserable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put some sample data in my test.text file :

```
name,age,location
Ram,12,UK
Jadu,11,USA
```

And the code I wrote to check if the header is present or not :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

csv = CSV.open("#{__dir__}/test.txt", :col_sep => ",", :headers => true )
p csv.read.headers
# >> ["name", "age", "location"]
```

Now this array you have to check, if it matches with your *headers* values. If it matched, then you can tell, yes header is applied.This code is written exactly on the same base as [`@tadman`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645186/is-there-any-way-to-determine-is-csv-with-header-or-not-in-rails/24645344#comment38201281_24645186) said :

> here's no standard way of defining headers in a CSV file, but convention dictates that the first line, and only the first line, is headers. People are free to do whatever they want and, in the process, make your life as a developer absolutely miserable.

To know what are these options mean `:col_sep`, `:headers` checkout the documentation of [`CSV::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new).